# Find Overlap In Time Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table in a SQL Server 2012 database that logs events, with columns `StartDate` and `EndDate`. I need to aggregate all of the records within a certain time period, and determine the duration of time where any events were active, not counting overlapping durations. For example, if my table looks like this:

```
 id     StartDate                EndDate
 =======================================================
 1     2017-08-28 12:00:00 PM    2017-08-28 12:01:00 PM
 2     2017-08-28 1:15:00 PM     2017-08-28 1:17:00 PM
 3     2017-08-28 1:16:00 PM     2017-08-28 1:20:00 PM
 4     2017-08-28 1:30:00 PM     2017-08-28 1:35:00 PM
```

And my time period to search was from `2017-08-28 12:00:00 PM` to `2017-08-28 2:00:00 PM`, then my desired output should be:

`Duration of Events Active = 00:11:00`

I have been able to aggregate the records and get a total duration (basically just `EndDate` - `StartDate`), but I cannot figure out how to exclude overlapping time. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a sample including overlaping to understand the border cases?

Comment: Break every interval down to a  set of rows  according the granuality you need (1 minute for example). Count distinct rows within the interval needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a CTE and aggregation? This can be done with a sub-query too.

```
declare @table table (id int, StartDate datetime, EndDate datetime)
insert into @table
values

( 1,'2017-08-28 12:00:00 PM','2017-08-28 12:01:00 PM'),
(2,'2017-08-28 1:15:00 PM','2017-08-28 1:17:00 PM'),
(3,'2017-08-28 1:16:00 PM','2017-08-28 1:20:00 PM'),
(4,'2017-08-28 1:30:00 PM','2017-08-28 1:35:00 PM')

declare @StartDate datetime = '2017-08-28 12:00:00'
declare @EndDate datetime = '2017-08-28 14:00:00'


;with cte as(
select
    id
    ,StartDate = case when StartDate < lag(EndDate) over (order by id) then lag(EndDate) over (order by id) else StartDate end
    ,EndDate
from 
    @table
where
    StartDate >= @StartDate
and EndDate <= @EndDate),


cte2 as(
select 
     Dur = datediff(second, StartDate, EndDate)
from cte)

select
    Dur = convert(varchar, dateadd(ms, sum(Dur) * 1000, 0), 114)
from
    cte2
```

Comment: This works! Just manually verified it with much more data. Thanks!

Comment: No worries @controller, just remember to add a partition in the lag statement if you need to partition the records by some other unique identifier.